# Give smooth effect of UIImage Stratch

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am Creating one application and i required following effects.
I don't know hot to start work. if any one know what is my first step for this effect then please guide me for how to stretch Hair like this.

[effects Link1](http://youtu.be/GQPtGyAktEw)

[effects Link2](http://youtu.be/v4FP7vVPEiI)

I used following link and tutorial but not succeeded.

http://code.google.com/p/faceworkshop/

http://code.google.com/p/imgwarp-opencv/

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/table_of_content_ios/table_of_content_ios.html#table-of-content-ios

I think, I am going to wrong way...Plz help me.

Comment: what is wrong with this question? why give down vote?

Answer (score 1):

The effect look alike it's an OpenGL object with a texture where you change the coordinates of the vertex nearest to the touch point. The OpenGL object has to be constructed out of triangles matching the form, which is probably done based on the hair image.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but how to start OpenGL Coding?

Comment: OpenGL is not trivial, but mighty. Always a good start: [OpenGL ES 2 Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial)