# Caricature effect to uiimage in iOS

Tags: ios, ios6, core-image

I'm trying to implement [Link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/caricature-me/id495103673?mt=8)application with core images with different filters. How can we implement this? I google for it but unable to find any api or sdk for it.

Can anyone help me for it?

Comment: i also found solution for this type of application. I asked question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402377/adjusting-the-line-to-fit-our-head-in-imageview and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701125/split-the-image-into-a-mesh-of-small-quadrangles-in-opengles

Comment: This looks very similar to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773356/caricature-in-ios. If that one was closed as "not a real question" you should try to provide *more* information, not *less*.

Comment: also ask http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370986/how-can-we-specify-the-warp-in-objective-c and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234753/give-smooth-effect-of-uiimage-stratch  but no one give me answer. If you find any answer than plz help me. Thank You

Comment: @MartinR ok thank you. I'll remember it for next time. sorry.

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD Ok i'll let you know once I get something.